# Why does owner user require sudo?

Tags: permissions, users, groups

This is a specific configuration that I found about [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-shared-directory-for-all-users-in-linux).

I have two users that share a common folder:

```
$ ls /home
> drwsrws--- root   my-group ... common
> drwxr-xr-x diego  diego    ... diego 
> drwxr-xr-x diego2 diego2   ... diego2
```

The common folder is owned by a group `my-group`, to which both users have been added.

If I log in with user `diego`, I can write and edit files in `common` folder.

But if I am using `diego2`, I have to use `sudo` in order to write and edit it.

I believe this has to do with `root` being the owner of that folder, and `diego` being a designated root... ¿does that even exist?

How can I be able to write and edit files in `common` folder as `diego2`?

FWIW:  the reason I created such configuration, is to be able to login to different desktop sessions `plasma` and `gnome` and not have to share all the settings.  The common folder is where I do work (except this is a personal pc, so coding projects), and is linked to corresponding folders in each of them.

Comment: `diego2` should not have to use `sudo`.  I think you'd have to give us more information.  Has `diego2` logged out and logged back in?  And then, can you type `groups diego` and then `groups diego2` and add the output to that to your question?  (Of course, both should have `my-group` listed.  Then, we'd look into what the `/home/common/` folder looks like and whether the permissions at the top have propagated down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make sure the sub-folders inside the folder `common` all had `my-group` as group.

For existing subfolders:

```
$ chown -R diego:my-group /home/common
```

And for new ones:

```
$ setguid g+sx /home/common/each-subfolder
```

=D

Answer (score 3):

Linux ignores setuid on directories, and uses setgid to set the group of the files created in it. So, when `diego` creates a file in `common`, it is owned by the user `diego`, and group `my-group`. However, the user's umask determines what the initial *permissions* of the created file are, and the default is to give only the owner write permissions. Which means `diego2` won't be able to modify those files.

Your options are:

1. Change the permissions on the existing files to add write permissions for group **and** set umask for both to `0002` so that both users create group-writeable files, which will affect *all* files they create. That might not be something you want to do. Or,
2. Use ACLs to add default permissions to the `common` directory (and also to existing files and directories in it) that allow both `diego` and `diego2` to write to them. (See [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1315/70524).)

Comment: While this answer does give hints on where to follow.  These were several steps deep, and I'm still working on how to figure it out.  Specifically, since I didn't know about `setuid` and `setgid` I had to learn those bits.  Thanks I guess.